# How do I reference Route and ResponseType Attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

My computer unexpectedly crashed while I was working in visual studio on a web application. As a result my csproj was completely corrupted, so I had to start a new web project and re-add all the files and assemblies from my old project.

But for some reason Route, which should be in System.Web.Http, and ResponseType, which should be in System.Web.Http.Description cannot be found, even though I still have the appropriate usings for them. Also, my project is still referencing `System.Web` and `System.Web.Http`, and all the other stuff in my application seems to not be generating any errors like this at the moment.

[image]

I've also tried writing out the full path to these classes (i.e. `System.Web.Http.Description.ResponseType`) but while intellisense is able to explore the namespace, the Route and ResponseType attributes are missing.

I'm not sure if this is related, but when I right-click on Controllers and select Add, I don't get an option to add a controller any more. Something got really messed up with this project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should re-install the necessary **packages** to enable `Attribute Routing`.

From the *Tools* menu in Visual Studio, select *Library Package Manager*, then select *Package Manager Console*. Enter the following command in the *Package Manager Console* window:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost
```

Then after manually adding relevant references (i.e `System.Web.dll` and `System.Web.Http.dll` if they aren't already referenced) and using proper `namespaces`, your attributes should work:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
```

Comment: For future reference, how is does one figure out which package needs to be installed? I've never heard of the "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" package.

Comment: There is a file called `packages.config` in the root of a vs project. This file contains the list of all installed packages. When creating a new vs project, depending on the project type, necessary packages will be installed automatically. I think when your system crashed, some of these packages were gone, so re-installing them manually may resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the accepted answer, I found that it was possible to automatically have the necessary packages installed as soon as the first Web API 2 controller is added to the project through the solution explorer's context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve for me by doing the following!

1. Save the solution
2. update-package -reinstall